# Verb used with "threshold"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, collocation

I am wondering what verb collocates with *threshold*. I can think of verbs such as *surpass, cross, pass*, but I am not sure if they are correct to use here.

The threshold I am referring to is not a physical one but rather some value. Specifically, if the threshold is 100 and the value is greater than that, then the threshold is ______?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referring to [threshold](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Threshold) meaning a *specific level or point* used in different fields such as Economics and Physics for instance, 
as [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exceed%20a%20threshold%2Csurpass%20a%20threshold%2Ccross%20a%20threshold%2C%20pass%20a%20threshold&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexceed%20a%20threshold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurpass%20a%20threshold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccross%20a%20threshold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpass%20a%20threshold%3B%2Cc0) shows *cross and exceed* are the verbs usually associated with it, but other combinations  are acceptable.

Threshold:

> - a level or point at which something would happen, would cease to happen, or would take effect, become true, etc
>     b. (as modifier): threshold price; threshold effect.
>     (General Physics)
> - the minimum intensity or value of a signal, etc, that will produce a response or specified effect: a frequency threshold.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: note though that "exceed" generally only means in one direction. Usually you want to cover crossing in either direction.  So just "crossing" - as in that previous sentence.

Answer (score 5):

It's just "crossed" or "passed".

**Exactly like a border:** For example, "I crossed the Swiss border" or "I passed the red house."

"surpass" is quite different. It simply means "better than".

Comment: Also exactly like a border, when the value goes from 99 to 101 it crosses the threshold, but when it goes from 101 to 99 it crosses the threshold as well.

Comment: Right. that's why there's a danger in using "exceed", since that is, generally, "one-way"

Answer (score 4):

In case of some value you can use "exceed".
e.g., If it is greater than 100, the threshold is exceeded.

Comment: again "exceed" is uni-directional.  no programmer would use it, for instance!  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm a programmer, I'd more likely use *exceed* than any other word to describe the event of a variable's value growing larger than a threshold. I might even name the function called in that event "thresholdExceeded".

Comment: *"describe the event of a variable's value growing larger than a threshold"*  For sure!  if you were kvo'ing it going in EITHER DIRECTION, you'd likely not use "exceed".  i'd try to write it only once for the two directions to save money :)

Comment: @JoeBlow You're aware that the example provided in the question is explicitly a case of transitioning from below a threshold to above it, right? This literally makes uni-directional answers to this question superior to the more ambiguous "multi-dimensional" ones.

Comment: "describe the event of a variable's value growing larger than a threshold" For sure! if you were kvo'ing it going in EITHER DIRECTION, you'd likely not use "exceed". i'd try to write it only once for the two directions to save money :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use "reached" and "unreached", not only when the threshold is a minimum value, but also when it's a maximum (i.e. when the sample value but be less than the threshold for the "activation").

In either case, the mathematical relationship is derived from the context.

E.g. 1 (threshold is a maximum)
Water boils at 100 degrees Celsius. When it **reaches this threshold**, it starts turning into vapors.

E.g. 2 (threshold is a minimum)
Water freezes at 0 degrees Celsius. When it **reaches this threshold**, it starts turning into ice.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if the crossing of threshold value is going to disrupt a system, 'breach' seems more appropriate.

For example: A new Cassandra cluster must be set up as the threshold for the keyspace count has been breached for the [string\|applicationName] application.